# WordPress custom post with different size featured images

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a custom post in wordpress which will be displayed like this following image (click the link)

[Output of the custom post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcFdz.jpg)

What will be the good practice for this? I sorted out a way but that will require 3 different custom posts for this single section. I want to create one custom post and my featured image size will be the output as shown in the picture.

I have created the custom post type, just can't sort out what do I need for the php file and css and/or any extra library. I am using bootstrap and have JQuery.

Comment: there are  total 10 images appearing which are actually only two images appearing 10 time one image is appearing two times and other one is appearing 8 times. If these images will be only two you  can upload two images if these will be 10 different images you will have to upload 10 or you can use gallery images.

Comment: the image was just the idea, there will be 10 different image

Comment: Show your code what you tried to render this section ?

Comment: you can create post thumnail for different image size

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;
foreach($yourArray as $array){
 if($i==4 || $i==5){
   // change your image html as per your requirement for two big image
  }
   // your html of other 8 same size images
 $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you need different thumbnail size for each post, You can upload same size image for all post and crop the image unsing BFI Thumb library based on condition.

Library for cropping images for specific dimension is available at below link.

https://github.com/bfintal/bfi_thumb